# Moving Android device to one direction but X-axis get both plus and minus value from the Accelerometer Sensor

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am currently working on an application that related to the Android accelerometer sensor. I want to monitor the movement of the android device based on the accelerometer data. But I got really frustrated because the data that provided by the accelerometer sensor doesn't make any sense to me. For example, I put the android device on the table and push it consistently from left to right. So the value in the X-axis should be at least negative and remain negative as the force is from left to right(I already get rid of the gravity influence on the accelerometer data). However, the data I get shows both positive and negative value, which is so weird to me because the force is one direction so the Acceleration should definitely be only negative. Here is my code:

```
    final float alpha = 0.8f;
    // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
    gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
    gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
    gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

    // Remove the gravity contribution with the high-pass filter.
    linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
    linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
    linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];

    dbManager.insertAccData(String.valueOf(primaryKey++),                    
    String.valueOf(linear_acceleration[0]),
    String.valueOf(linear_acceleration[1]),
    String.valueOf(linear_acceleration[2]));
```

I did the movement as I described before and put the linear_acceleration data into SQLliteDatabase for further analysis. The graph below is the data I get from the SQLliteDatabase.

[I export the linear_acceleration data to Excel and create this graphy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd1Ac.png)

As we can see, there are two curves show the plus data but one shows the minus value, which is not reasonable because I don't think there is any opposite force generated when I push the device from the left to the right, so I am so struggling with these two curves above the value of 0. Could any one help me with this and save my life on that.  Thanks so much in advence!